# How to remove duplicates from my array of structs?

Tags: c++-cli, duplicates

Here is my code that reads structs from a file.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    typedef struct
    {

        char  name_1[100];
        char Max_1[100];
        char Min_1[100];
    } power_line_name;
    int numLines;
    StreamReader ^ sr1=File::OpenText("testcpp\\test\\powerline.txt");
    while(sr1->ReadLine())
    {
        numLines++;
    }
    power_line_name* power_list=new power_line_name[numLines];
    //power_line_name power_list[5];
    StreamReader ^ sr=File::OpenText("testcpp\\test\\powerline.txt");
    array<System::String ^> ^power_line;
    array<System::String ^> ^d_line;
    String ^ eachString;
    String ^ eachString_2;
    String ^ eachString_3;
    int i=0;
    char nstring[100];
    try
    {
        String^ s="";
        while (s=sr->ReadLine())
        {
            power_line=s->Split(':');
            Console::WriteLine(s);
            d_line=power_line[1]->Split('|');
            for(int a=0;a<d_line->Length;a++)
            {
                pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(d_line[a]);
                size_t origsize = wcslen(wch) + 1;
                size_t convertedChars = 0;
                if(a==0)
                {
                    wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, power_list[i].name_1, origsize, wch, _TRUNCATE);
                    strcat_s(power_list[i].name_1, " (char *)");
                }
                if(a==1)
                {
                    wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, power_list[i].Max_1, origsize, wch, _TRUNCATE);
                    strcat_s(power_list[i].Max_1, " (char *)");
                }
                if(a==2)
                {
                    wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, power_list[i].Min_1, origsize, wch, _TRUNCATE);
                    strcat_s(power_list[i].Min_1, " (char *)");
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

        Console::WriteLine(s);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(sr)
            delete (IDisposable^)(sr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is its output:

```
power_list[0].name_1=aaaa

power_list[0].Max_1=1111111

power_list[0].Min_1=222222

power_list[1].name_1=aaaa

power_list[1].Max_1=333333

power_list[1].Min_1=444444

power_list[2].name_1=aaaa

power_list[2].Max_1=333333

power_list[2].Min_1=444444

power_list[3].name_1=aaaa

power_list[3].Max_1=33333

power_list[3].Min_1=66666
```

If `Max_1` and `Min_1` are the same for some two elements, I would like the second element to be removed.

So the new ouput would be:

```
power_list[0].name_1=aaaa

power_list[0].Max_1=1111111

power_list[0].Min_1=222222

power_list[1].name_1=aaaa

power_list[1].Max_1=333333

power_list[1].Min_1=444444

power_list[2].name_1=aaaa

power_list[2].Max_1=33333

power_list[2].Min_1=66666
```

i don't know how to do??

Comment: The C++ standard library have many nice [algorithmic functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) built-in, for example to [remove duplicates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique). Though for C++CLI you should search [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) for something appropriate.

Comment: This code looks like CLI/.Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with c++-cli syntax, so here is one way to do it, in pseudo-code:

```
for i from 0 to n-1
    for j from i+1 to n-1
        if list[i].Max_1 == list[j].Max_1 and list[i].Min_1 == list[j].Min_1
            mark j as duplicate

for i from 0 to n-1
    if i is not marked duplicate
        output i
```

This seems to be the simplest way to do it.

Another more sophisticated way: sort your array; then all duplicate entries will be adjacent, which will make comparisons easier. Maybe someone else will describe this in another answer.